# Game Center Implementation Error - Apple Mach-O

Tags: xcode, game-center

I need help this is my error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameCenterManager", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am trying to implement game center.

This is my ViewController.h #import:

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import "GameCenterManager.h"
```

This is my ViewController.m #import:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppSpecificValues.h"
#import "GameCenterManager.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Xcode Linker Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660718/xcode-linker-error/11772282#11772282) worked for me

> Go to your project, click on Build phases, Compile sources, Add `GameCenterManager.m` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to import the `GameKit` framework into your project. Also put `#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>` at the top of `ViewController`'s header file.

Comment: I assume that the GameCenterManager.h file has a corresponding implementation file in the project hierarchy?

Comment: Can you post how you're instantiating the `GameCenterManager` class in your code? It is possible that you're creating the object incorrectly, which is triggering a memory leak.

Comment: class GameCenterManager;

    interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate, GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate, GameCenterManagerDelegate> {
    
    GameCenterManager *gameCenterManager;
    int64_t  currentScore;
    NSString* currentLeaderBoard;
    IBOutlet UILabel *currentScoreLabel;
    
}

Comment: there are supposed to be @ symbols in front of the class & interface

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Go to your project Build Settings and select the Architecture as armv6 or armv7. Clean up your project and build again.